# Можно ли запретить редактирование части текста в tinimce?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce

Собственно весь вопрос в заголовке. Можно ли запретить редактировать часть текста, если можно - как?

К примеру у меня есть текст:

```
Шла Саша по шо(...)е и сосала сушку.
```

Вот как мне разрешить редактировать только ту часть, где  `(...)`

Comment: А зачем для этого целый TinyMCE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут похоже три варианта. Если нужно просто редактировать небольшие участки текста (это к примеру тест по английскому и нужно вствлять пропущенные слова/буквы), то я бы просто повставлял обычные поля ввода. Но можно и скриптов прикрутить и по клику на слово с подчеркиваниями/точками показывать поле ввода. Также не забыть обработать правильно tab.

Если же объем текста большой и это один кусок, то никто не машает показать текст, потом tinymce с нужным текстом, потом снова текст.

И третий вариант - есть большой текст и на  редактирование каждого параграфа нужно установить свои права на редактирование (странная задача, но всякое бывает). В этом случае решение не сильно отличается от первого случая - каждый логический кусок текста при клике по нем отображается в редакторе. Это все можно сделать очень красиво и прозрачно. То есть, получается такой себе "параграф ориентированный редактор".

Comment: Проблема в том что мне на выходе нужен весь текст, а не его части. То есть мне нужно получить post, в котором будет целая строка.

Comment: Это решается в несколько строк на javascript с jQuery.

Comment: Да в том то и дело, что понимаю как объединить, но что то не выходит, но в любом случае - уже решил вроде проблему эту - спасибо.